# Substrate Node to light Client

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, rust, light-client

How can I make substrate node light as light client ? If we want to build a light client can it be possible to make changes in substrate node and make it a light client.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of your question is not clear to me. How "light" do you mean? Where should it run?
All substrate compatible chains or just Polkadot?

Did you have a look at [substrate-connect](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-connect) or [Smoldot](https://github.com/paritytech/smoldot).

Comment: Yes I want to design similar to smoldot , can I build using substrate node or  to fork the smoldot repository and make changes to it

Comment: The Substrate node does much more than a light client. For example it can author blocks or provide historic information. A light client does just a fraction of that; mainly following consensus through verifying proofs. The scope of your question is to open-ended to be answered precisely. Sure you can fork Smoldot if you want something similar.

Comment: Ok how to connect smoldot to substrate based blockchain ?

Comment: Exactly as written in the [README](https://github.com/paritytech/smoldot#wasm-light-node): `cd bin/wasm-node/javascript && npm i && npm start`.